# How to merge two bitmaps (overlap)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm trying to merge two `Bitmap`. I have a resource on my `Drawable` and I get the `Bitmap` as :

```
val defaultBitmap = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.default_image)!!.toBitmap()
```

Then I have another but comes from an url and then I convert it to `Bitmap`

```
Glide.with(requireContext())
 .asBitmap()
 .load("url")
 .override(32,32)
 .into(object: CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
       //whatever
    }

    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) { }
 }
)
```

And then the way I'm trying to merge is :

```
val defaultBitmap = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.default_image)!!.toBitmap()
val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(defaultBitmap.width, defaultBitmap.height, defaultBitmap.config)
val twiseImage = Canvas(resultBitmap)
twiseImage.drawBitmap(defaultBitmap, Matrix(), null)
twiseImage.drawBitmap(bitmapGlide, 0f,0f,null)
```

The thing is that I'd like to end up is :

[image]

Number 1 is the default one and the Number 2 is the glide one, I want to be in the center of the Number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [drawBitmap (bitmap, left, top, paint)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)):

```
val defaultBitmap = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.default_image)!!.toBitmap()
val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(defaultBitmap.width, defaultBitmap.height, defaultBitmap.config)
val twiseImage = Canvas(resultBitmap)
val x = (defaultBitmap.width - bitmapGlide.width) / 2
val y = (defaultBitmap.height - bitmapGlide.height) / 2
twiseImage.drawBitmap(bitmapGlide, x, y, null)
```

You could also translate the canvas by (x,y) and draw at the (0,0) coordinates.